# How to Import Sample ApiDemos into Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, github

At the end of http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html is stated "For more samples using fragments (**and complete source files for this example**), **see the API Demos sample app available in ApiDemos** (available for download from the Samples SDK component)."

However, **ApiDemos** is *not* listed anywhere among the hundreds of items when I try to `Import sample...` in AS 1.5.1. ADVANCED ApiDemos is listed, but the description says this is NOT what I seek.

It sure would be nice to accomplish this task in one step as advertised instead of having to download each individual file (and worry if the app will work because of some omission) from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/APIDemo.

Is there a way to `Import sample...` ApiDemos somehow?

Comment: What demo are you trying to find?

Comment: The sample you linked to is for ads, not Fragments. The link from the Fragments page is out of date, but you can view all the Android samples from [this link](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html) by expanding the sections of the left side of the page.

Comment: I want the entire app being developed at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Like I said, those sample links are outdated. Each code-block is a standalone section that reading the whole page should tell you where to put it. If you would like a less dense tutorial on Fragments, I recommend you search elsewhere.

Comment: The code for the tutorial in question is fairly short. Nothing on the whole page suggests the app in the tutorial. There was a link to download its predecessor which was painless. I just expected the same for the next tutorial. No such luck. I'll probably try to create the project from the files shown on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reasonable place to find help with `Fragment` is on one's own computer:

`...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\samples\android-17\`**ApiDemos**`\src\com\example\android\apis\app`

A search for **`ArticleReaderFragment`** (a `Fragment` in the tutorial) in the parent folder `C:\Users\Dov\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\samples\android-17\ApiDemos`  turned up nothing, so the sample code in question isn't there, but lots of `Fragment*.java` files could be profitable in one's self-education on the topic.

[image]

While not stored with any app, lots of `xml` files can be found here:

`...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\samples\android-17\ApiDemos\res`

`FragmentLayout.java` is reasonably close to the app in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can download an archive of `ApiDemos` directly from here.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos

Not sure if there is a direct git link, because as you can see, it is under the `sample` directory of the `platform/development` repository.

You are more than welcome to clone the whole 300+ MB of the android-development repository and get access to `ApiDemos` (and much more) like so

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development android-development
$ cd android-development/samples/ApiDemos
```

Comment: I believe all of those files are found in the user's computer folder listed in my Answer.

Comment: Possibly, but yours would be API17 whereas mine would always be the latest samples unless you switch branches

Comment: The files are also found in similar folder `...\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\samples\android-23` and with search capability on one's computer to find the associated `xml` files, I think this will do nicely for the purpose of trying to figure out `Fragment`.

Comment: Whatever works for you :) I'm comfortable searching files from the terminal

Answer (score 1):

There is no `samples` folder under android sdk for Android Studio 2.1.2. I ended up getting API folders from the link provided by @cricket_007. Also, don't waste time looking for the Fragment sample code in https://github.com/googlesamples because its not there. It only has the latest sample codes.

[image: sdk manager]

[image]